# Check duplicate row doesn't already exist

Tags: mysql, sql

**Tables:**

```
exp_submissions
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
id | entry_id | member_id | member_group | category_id | type_id | portfolio_number
```

```
exp_judging
------------------------------------------------
id | rel_id | judge_id | pre | stage_1 | stage_2
```

**The aim:**

- Join the two tables together on `exp_judging.rel_id`, and `exp_submissions.id`
- Only select rows where :

  - `exp_submissions.member_group = 5` and `exp_judging.pre = 1`
  - `judge_id != 1`, or `judge_id IS NULL`
  - there is no existing rows with the same `rel_id` and `judge_id = 1`.

The following query does everything up to the last part:

```
SELECT sub.entry_id 
FROM exp_judging AS jud
LEFT JOIN exp_submissions AS sub ON jud.rel_id = sub.id 
WHERE (jud.judge_id != 1 OR jud.judge_id IS NULL)
AND jud.pre = 1
AND sub.member_group = 5
LIMIT 1
```

These are the test rows I have in my exp_judging table:

[image]

As you will see, there is two rows with the `rel_id = 35` (ID 200 and 197). 
The above query is selecting the row id 197 even though there is another row with the same `rel_id` and has a `judge_id = 1`. This is my issue.

I need to add to my query to check that no other row exists with the same `rel_id` and `judge_id = 1`, but I can't figure out how.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shoud use a `NOT EXISTS` clause:

```
   SELECT sub.entry_id 
     FROM exp_judging AS jud
LEFT JOIN exp_submissions AS sub ON jud.rel_id = sub.id 
    WHERE (jud.judge_id != 1 OR jud.judge_id IS NULL)
      AND jud.pre = 1
      AND sub.member_group = 5
      AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT sub2.entry_id 
                        FROM exp_judging AS jud2
                   LEFT JOIN exp_submissions AS sub2 ON jud2.rel_id = sub2.id 
                       WHERE (jud2.judge_id = 1 )
                         AND jud2.pre = 1
                         AND sub2.member_group = 5
                         AND jud2.rel_id = jud.rel_id)
    LIMIT 1
```

Edit: added a new condition

Comment: Thanks Oscar. I have tried this, but am unable to get the desired result. Even if I delete the row 200, it still shows no results. It should then show 1, as row 197 does not have the same judge_id, and there are no rows existing with judge_id '1' and rel_id '35'.

Comment: Try now, I added a new condition

Comment: Spot ON! Thank you, this has been killing. I will study your query!!